# Uso de memoria do codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, memória

Fiz minha primeira aplicação em codeigniter, a principio estava funcionando tudo certo.
Porem quando olhei a memoria do servidor, ela esta muito alta, começa com pouco uso, e a cada requisição ela aumenta o uso e não libera mais.
Não sei o que fazer no momento. Já usei o codigo `$db['default']['save_queries'] = FALSE;`

Mas não adiantou, adicionei o codigo

```
function __destruct() {
    unset($this);
}
```

para tentar liberar a memoria utilizada no $this, mas também não adiantou praticamente nada.

Alguma ideia de como liberar a memoria usada?

Obrigado

Comment: seria bom fazer um profiling da aplicação, tenho uma questão sobre isso, até agora so conheço o zend studio como boa ferramenta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28784/profiling-php-debug-tempo-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Já vi o `Codeigniter` dar uns bugs assim mesmo. Por exemplo: Eu já fiz uma teste, enviando dados grandes via `POST` (formulário) em um sistema feito no `Codeigniter`, e o  mesmo gerou um erro fatal (exaustão de memória).

Comment: Ao invés de `unset($this)`, tenta trocar por `$this->db->close()` no model principal :)

Answer (score 1):

Também já tive problemas com excesso de uso de memória e escrevi esse pequeno ciclo para libertar tudo no final de cada load da aplicação.

Faça `print_r` de `memory_get_usage()`e `memory_get_peak_usage()` para ver o antes e depois de correr o ciclo:

```
// DEVELOPMENT
print_r(memory_get_usage()); echo '<br>'; // Antes
print_r(memory_get_peak_usage()); echo '<br>';

foreach (array_keys(get_defined_vars()) as $var){
    unset($$var);
}

// DEVELOPMENT
print_r(memory_get_usage()); echo '<br>'; // Depois
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha acho que pode ser o modo que foi desenvolvido, o CI faz muitos includes.
quanto mais $this->load usar mais memoria vai consumir.

Mas tem que ver também se o consumo de memoria é do php ou do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Este estouro de memória pode ser o salvamento automático da última consulta, você pode usar `$this->db->save_queries = false;` ou alterar o arquivo config/database.php para `'save_queries' => FALSE,`