# profiling php (debug + tempo de execução)

Tags: php, memória, debug

Alguém utiliza profiling de códigos php, sem ser com zend studio?

O problema do zend studio é a licença... mas é muito boa essa funcionalidade, existe algo open source que não seja tão complicado quanto xdebug e suas muitas configurações, ou seja, que esta funcionalidade seja do software IDE, que não precise de ajustes em php.ini e etc...

Segue imagem de exemplo do profiling zend studio

http://www.onlamp.com/onlamp/2008/03/11/images/Zend%20Studio%206.0%20-%20Profiler.jpg

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @bigown achei algo bem parecido http://www.phpmetrics.org/

Comment: achei uma solução: https://blackfire.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o autor encontrou uma solução alternativa é o [brackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/).

### Pré-requisitos

Antes de instalar o Blackfire, é requerido algumas configurações técnicas:

- Probe, Agent e Client devem funcionar no Linux e MacOS X.
- O servidor funcionar com PHP 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 e 5.6.
- O **Companion** é atualmente apenas suportado pelo Google Chrome.
- O site funcionar em todos browsers atuais (não funciona no IE).

### Instando

Existe um método de instalação para cada servidor

1. Siga os passos para o seu sistema https://blackfire.io/getting-started#installation
2. Configure conforme as especificações do seu sistema https://blackfire.io/doc/configuration (aparentemente funciona com Nginx e Apache)

### Usando

1. Faça o login no [brackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/);
2. Navegue para URL que pretende obter o profile
3. Abra o **Companion** clicando nos ícones da barra de ferramentas do navegador;
4. Selecione o "slot" que deseja usar
5. Clique no botão "Profile"
6. Após alguns segundos clique no "View profile"